# How does signed 16bit addition work in avr-gcc?

Tags: assembly, avr, avr-gcc

I am trying to understand how to do signed addition between 2 16-bit numbers in avr assembly.

Given this C code:

```
#include <stdbool.h>

int16_t my_fun(const int16_t x, bool is_positive){
    const int16_t y = 10000 * (is_positive? 1 : -1);
    return x + y;
}
```

`avr-gcc` outputs (simplified to be more readable):

```
my_fun:
    cpse r22,r1
    rjmp positive
    ldi r18,-16
    ldi r19,-40
    rjmp add_them
positive:
    ldi r18,16
    ldi r19,39
add_them:
    add r24,r18
    adc r25,r19
    ret
```

I understand that `x`'s lower byte is in `r24` and higher byte in `r25`. Also, the return value is in the same registers. `r18` and `r19` store `y`'s lower and higher byte.

My questions are: in the positive case `r18` and `r19` get `16` and `39` (`39*256+16==10000`) but why do they get `-40` instead of `-39` in the negative case?
How do signed multi-byte numbers are represented in general and how do we add them?

Comment: -40 is 216 unsigned, -16 is 240 unsigned which gives 55536 unsigned which is -10000 signed. Or in other words -10000 is 0xD8F0 hex, which has the given low and high bytes. See [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement). Addition itself works the same.

Comment: addition and subtraction have no notion of signed or unsigned.  Multiply and divide, sure, but add and subtract not.  Part of the beauty of twos complement.

Answer (score 0):

Extended precision integers are stored in chunks (usually of the machine word size, which is 1B for AVR, but 4B for x86-32.).  [GMP (the gnu multi-precision library)](https://gmplib.org/) calls these chunks "limbs".

In your case, you have all the chunks of both numbers in registers (after the `ldi` instructions).  They can be stored in memory like an array or struct would be.

Since carry/borrow propagates from LSB to MSB in addition and subtraction, the sequence of machine instructions for adding them begins with a normal `add` on the LSB which sets the carry flag (or not), followed by `adc` (add-with-carry) instructions for all the rest of the chunks.  `adc` reads and writes the carry flag.

`add` / `adc` is the same sequence you'd see on x86 for adding a 64bit number in 32bit mode, or for a 128b number in 64b mode.  (x86 uses the same mnemonics as AVR for those insns.)